# How to tell PHP to stop when it reaches the end of the line without returning an error?

Tags: php, while-loop, text-files

I am trying to read the content of a text-file, but have no idea how to tell PHP to break when it has reached the end.

The current code is:

```
<?php

$file = "campaign1_20_db.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$string = explode("\n",$content);

$index = 0;

while ($index <= 100):

$index = $index + 1;
endwhile;

?>
```

How do i replace the 100 with something that depends on PHP reaching the end of the textfile?

Comment: Why don't you just loop over the `$string` array?

Comment: do you mean to stop the execution?

Comment: I am not familiar with the PHP syntax. Trying to grasp how to use it.

Comment: Mahan, yeah. I wish to get PHP to stop the loop at that point.

Comment: @TingPing start by reading the concept of working with the [filesystem](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php) in PHP, this question is obviously very cryptic due to your unfamiliarity with the language PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using explode, you'll have an array of lines. However, you could simply have:

```
$strings = file($file);
```

which does the exact same thing for you without the explict explode. You can then simply do a foreach loop on that array:

```
foreach($strings as $line) {
  ...
}
```

to loop over each of those lines. However, it appears you're just trying to count how many lines there are, so the foreach isn't even necessary:

```
$total_lines = count($strings);
```

Comment: I am not trying to count the number of lines. I have a text-file which contains the data i need to populate into a html formatted table. So, I am trying to use while loop to get everything in the text-file.

Answer (score 1):

(I hope you have there something more complex than counting lines one by one, otherwsie disregard this answer)

You may use lighter (in terms of consumed memory) algorithm to iterate through files' lines:

```
$f = fopen('campaign1_20_db.txt');
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if you have reached the end of the file, then you have to use the good old way of fopen, fread and feof. Code would be something like

```
 <?php
$file = fopen("file.txt");
while(!feof($file))  {
$content .= fread( $file, 1024 );
}
```

**Feof**

The function you are looking at is called file end of. This basically tells that you have reached at the end of the file or not.

**Fread**

In the fread command, you are passing the file handler (returned by fopen) and the amount of bytes that have to be read. The maximum value depends on your PHP settings.